# How to save date in database from frontend?

Tags: magento-1.9, datepicker

I want to add birthdate from frontend form using datepicker

**phtml code:**

```
<div class="field">
    <label class="required" for="birthday"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Date of birth');?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" title="Birthday" id="birthday" name="birthday" value="" style="  float: left;margin-right: 7px;max-width: 150px;">
        <img  title="Select Date" id="date" class="v-middle" alt="" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("images/calendar.gif");?> "/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            Calendar.setup({
                inputField: "birthday",
                ifFormat: "%m/%e/%Y",
                showsTime: false,
                button: "date",
                align: "Bl",
                singleClick : true
                });
            //]]>
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

**save data**

```
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $post_data = $this->_filterDates($post_data, array('birthdate', 'expiry_date'));
    $student = Mage::getModel('school/student');
    $student->setData($data);
    $student->save();
```

in $data i m getting date like this **05/7/2015** but in database this date is not saved. it saved default value. how can i save date from frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should clear the cache. Even if the cache is disabled the table schemas are cached and your field might not be recognized when calling `DESCRIBE TABLE` in order to match the data to the table columns.
Second, you should take a look at how `$student->getData()` looks like before calling `$student->save()`. See if your  `birthdate` field exists and take a look at the value it has.